# How do I make this simple OpenGL code (works in a "lenient" 3.3 and 4.2 profile) work in a strict 3.2 and 4.2 core profile?

Tags: opengl, go, opengl-3, opengl-4, vertex-attributes

I had some 3D code that I noticed wouldn't render in a strict core profile but fine in a "normal" (not explicitly requested-as-core-only) profile context. To isolate the issue, I have written the smallest simplest possible OpenGL program drawing just a triangle and a rectangle:

[image]

I have posted that OpenGL program [as a Gist here](http://gist.github.com/3950516).

With the *useStrictCoreProfile* variable set to false, the program outputs no error messages to the console and draws a quad and a triangle as per the above screenshot, both on an Intel HD OpenGL 3.3 and on a GeForce with OpenGL 4.2.

**However**, with *useStrictCoreProfile* set to true, it clears the background color but does not draw the tri & quad, console output is this:

```
GLCONN: OpenGL 3.2.0 @ NVIDIA Corporation GeForce GT 640M LE/PCIe/SSE2 (GLSL: 1.50 NVIDIA via Cg compiler)
LASTERR: OpenGL error at step 'render.VertexAttribPointer()': GL_INVALID_OPERATION
LASTERR: OpenGL error at step 'render.DrawArrays()': GL_INVALID_OPERATION
LASTERR: OpenGL error at step 'render.VertexAttribPointer()': GL_INVALID_OPERATION
LASTERR: OpenGL error at step 'render.DrawArrays()': GL_INVALID_OPERATION
LASTERR: OpenGL error at step '(post loop)': GL_INVALID_OPERATION
EXIT
```

... if a 4.2 strict core profile is requested instead of 3.2, same issue. Applies to 3 different nvidia GPUs so I assume I'm not conforming to the strict core profile properly. What was I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

Note, you won't find a **glEnableVertexAttribArray** call in the above Gist, as it's [inside the glutil package](http://github.com/go3d/go-util/blob/master/gl/shaders.go#L58) I'm importing -- but this does get called as the last step in the gist's **compileShaders()** func.

Comment: Have you tried using the GL_ARB_debug_output extension to get more useful error messages than "GL_INVALID_OPERATION"? It's a bit of a hassle to set up, but absolutely worth it.

Comment: +1 for sharing an example of a smallest simplest possible OpenGL program for Go

Comment: Well to be fair, it's not *really* the "smallest simplest-possible OpenGL program for Go", to be fair... one could cut it down  ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're not creating/binding a [Vertex Array Object](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) with [glGenVertexArrays()](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGenVertexArrays) and [glBindVertexArray()](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBindVertexArray). VAOs encapsulate a bunch of vertex attribute state, including which attributes are enabled, detailed per-attribute information, etc. They were optional when the feature was originally introduced, but they're now required in strict/core contexts according to section 10.4 of [the OpenGL core specification](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/current_version/):

> An INVALID_OPERATION error is generated by any commands which
>   modify, draw from, or query vertex array state when no vertex array is bound.
>   This occurs in the initial GL state, and may occur as a result of BindVertexArray or a side effect of DeleteVertexArrays.

Here's a very rough example of how VAOs are used:

```
// At initialization time:
GLuint vao = 0;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
// Set up your vertex attribute state:
//  - glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,...);
//  - glEnableVertexAttribArray(...);
//  - glVertexAttribPointer(...);
//  - etc. -- Refer to OpenGL docs to see what is/isn't included in the VAO!
glBindVertexArray(0); // unbinds vao

// At draw time:
glBindVertexArray(vao); // automatically sets up previously-bound vertex attribute state
glDrawArrays(...);
glBindVertexArray(0); // unbinds vao
```

Comment: Wow, I dug around some more based on your answer and what you're saying really seems to be the case... will try it and report back!

Comment: And you're right! That's it. Will stick to core profile from now on during development to catch such things earlier.

Comment: Great! What I'd love to see is some official OpenGL doc (rather than forum/SE posts) that confirms this difference (and others) between compatibility and core GL contexts, but so far I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: Well to be fair... the spec pdf for the strict core profile totally mentions this and I believe is actually quite complete -- but a caveman coder like me will tweak endlessly and ask in forums for days before taking half an hour to study and inspect the relevant sections...  ;))

Comment: Hey, you're right, there it is! Let me update my answer with an actual spec citation...

Comment: +1 for "caveman coding". I believe you just coined a new term.