# Why glDrawArrays fails with GL_INVALID_OPERATION?

Tags: opengl, go

I am using OpenGL to draw a rectangle, and I am doing this with golang.

I am not using red, green, blue argument for now.

```
var vertices = []float64{ 
    -1.0, -1.0,  0.0,   // V1 - bottom left 
    -1.0,  1.0,  0.0,   // V2 - top left 
    1.0, -1.0,  0.0,    // V3 - bottom right 
    1.0,  1.0,  0.0,    // V4 - top right 
}

func DisplayWrite(red []byte, green []byte, blue []byte) {
    const GL_TRUE = 1
    const GL_FALSE = 0
    const GL_FLOAT = 0x1406
    const GL_VERTEX_ARRAY = 0x8074
    const GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP = 0x0005
    C.glLoadIdentity();
    chkGlErr("glLoadIdentity")
    C.glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5.0);
    chkGlErr("glTranslatef")
    C.glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    chkGlErr("glEnableClientState")
    C.glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    chkGlErr("glColor4f")
    C.glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, (unsafe.Pointer)(&vertices));
    chkGlErr("glVertexPointer")
    C.glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (C.GLsizei)(len(vertices) / 3));
    chkGlErr("glDrawArrays")
    C.glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    chkGlErr("glDisableClientState")
    const GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE = 0x1401
    //C.glDrawPixels(Width, Height, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &red[0])
    //C.glDrawPixels(Width, Height, GL_GREEN, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &green[0])
    //C.glDrawPixels(Width, Height, GL_GREEN, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &blue[0])
}
```

Problem is when I call glDrawArrays like this:

```
C.glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (C.GLsizei)(len(vertices) / 3));
```

It draws nothing and error is GL_INVALID_OPERATION.
Is something wrong with the way I draw something?

This is setup part:

```
func DisplayInit() DispInitStatus {
    //(EGL and OpenGL ES initialization codes...)

    C.glViewport(0, 0, (C.GLsizei)(dWidth), (C.GLsizei)(dHeight));
    chkGlErr("glViewport")
    C.glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    chkGlErr("glMatrixMode")
    C.glLoadIdentity();
    chkGlErr("glLoadIdentity")

    makeFrustum(45.0, (float64)(dWidth) / (float64)(dHeight), 0.1, 100.0)

    C.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    chkGlErr("glMatrixMode")
    C.glLoadIdentity();
    chkGlErr("glLoadIdentity")

    //C.glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    //chkGlErr("glHint")
    C.glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    chkGlErr("glClearColor")
    C.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    chkGlErr("glClear")
    fmt.Println("EGL/GLES is now ready")
    return Disp_Ok
    //No error with these.
}
```

And main function

(DisplayUpdate does glFlush and eglSwapBuffers. It works with no problem.)

```
func main() {
    runtime.LockOSThread()
    DisplayInit()
    red := make([]byte, dWidth*dHeight)
    gre := make([]byte, dWidth*dHeight)
    blu := make([]byte, dWidth*dHeight)
    DisplayWrite(red, gre, blu)
    DisplayUpdate()
    for {
    }
}
```

I googled and found this:

[Why does OpenGL's glDrawArrays() fail with GL_INVALID_OPERATION under Core Profile 3.2, but not 3.3 or 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051587/why-does-opengls-gldrawarrays-fail-with-gl-invalid-operation-under-core-profi)

And I tried using runtime.LockOSThread() like above, but still doesn't work.

ADD: Added makeFrustum.

```
func makeFrustum(fovY, aspectRatio, front, back float64) {
    tangent := math.Tan(fovY / 2 * (3.14159265 / 180.0));   // tangent of half fovY
    height := front * tangent;          // half height of near plane
    width := height * aspectRatio;      // half width of near plane
    // params: left, right, bottom, top, near, far
    C.glFrustumf((C.GLfloat)(-width), (C.GLfloat)(width), (C.GLfloat)(-height), (C.GLfloat)(height), (C.GLfloat)(front), (C.GLfloat)(back));
    chkGlErr("glFrustumf")
}
```

This causes no error, too.

This does same thing as gluPerspective.

https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
C.glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
C.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (unsafe.Pointer)(&vertices));
```

`glVertexPointer` and `glVertexAttribPointer` are not the same function. If you're using old "client state" vertex arrays, then you meant `glVertexPointer`. `glVertexAttribPointer` is for doing shader-based rendering.

Comment: I also tried glVertexPointer. But It didn't worked, too. I edited question.